# Oracle group by clause in order of the data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by

I am trying to group the data below in a particular order that I have received it in my PL/SQL procedure. A custom table type FOIL_MAP is populated in my procedure and currently contains the data as shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovZEQ.png

I wrote the query:

```
select Foil_Keys, count(Foil_Keys) FCNT from Table(FOIL_MAP) group by Foil_Keys;
```

I got the Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe6z7.png

Is there any way to make the group by clause to return the data in the exact order that it was given in! Like this image shown below?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e06Lj.png

Comment: just add an order by to the end of the query

Comment: Order by what column?

Comment: Whatever column you want.  In this case it looks like you want to order by foil keys desc

Comment: Nope! I do not want to order it any manner! I just want the data to be in the same order as it is captured in the custom table FOIL_MAP

Comment: ok then see @The Impaler comment below

Answer (score 1):

```
select Foil_Keys, count(Foil_Keys) FCNT from Table(FOIL_MAP) group by Foil_Keys
order by foil_keys desc
```

Comment: This ain't a group by expression!

Answer (score 1):

> ...to return the data in the exact order that it was given in...

No, I'm sorry but no.

You want to return the data in the order it was inserted into the table. The SQL standard does not specify any order when returning the rows. The database can return the data in any order and that's OK; the order may even change in time. Now, if you want any particular order you need to use `ORDER BY`.

**Alternative Solution with Extra Column**

Anyway, if you want to return the data in the order it was inserted, then you'll need to add an extra column in the table to represent the date/time of the data insertion. If you do that, you could order by that column.

If a timestamp column is not good enough due to tiny granularity of your inserts (so there could be collissions in values) then you can use a sequence.

```
alter table foil_map add (my_order decimal(12) not null);

create sequence insert_order_seq;
```

and when inserting into the table:

```
insert into foil_map (col1, col2, ..., my_order)
  values (val1, val2, ..., insert_order_seq.nextval);
```

and your query would become:

```
select foil_keys, count(foil_keys) fcnt 
  from foil_map 
  group by foil_keys 
  order by max(my_order);
```

Comment: You get my point! I want it to be grouped exactly in the order in which the data was inserted. But, I am not able to capture the difference in the timestamps as the server I am working on is pretty fast and it does actually insert all the data at the exact same timestamp!

Comment: Then, use a sequence to populate an extra column, and then order by it.

Comment: Added the sequence option that will work even if inserts a blazing fast.

Comment: Yes, I did populate the sequence! Still not able to order by!

Comment: See the query: `order by max(my_order)`